# Firebase cloud functions https, calling API not working for me

Tags: firebase, react-native, axios, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to learn firebase cloud functions and I want to call an API using it but the console log shows that no data is being fetched, even though the function is deployed successfully/

Firebase function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');

exports.fetchList = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) =>{
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums').then((data) =>{
        response.send(data)
    }).catch((e) =>{
        console.log(e)
    })
})
```

App component:

```
componentWillMount() {
        axios({
            method:'POST',
            url: 'link from the console website',
        }).then((data) =>{
            console.log(data.data);
        }).catch((e) =>{
            console.log(e);
        })
}
```

Comment: On which pricing plan are you? The "Spark" plan? If yes, note that you need to be on the "Blaze" pricing plan.As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title). Since https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com is not a Google-owned API, you may need to switch to the "Blaze" plan.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see that data from the `fetchList` data logged to the Firebase console, you need to insert a `console.log` before you send a response.

```
const dataToLog = axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
  .then(dataToLog => {
    console.log(dataToLog);
    response.send(dataToLog);
}).catch // etc.
```

Also, probably obvious, but of course you'd need to put in the actual function URL endpoint in your component, not the string `link from the console website`.

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding your question!

Comment: I do want to the data from fetchList, your method didn't work tho, I did put the URL xDD